# Gulp no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet

Tags: gulp

tengo el lo siguiente como lo podria solucionar

```
PS F:\proyecto> gulp
gulp : El término 'gulp' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió
correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ gulp
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Tengo windows 10 64 Bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[solucionado] era un problema con la version de nodejs me exigia v7.0 o superior, estaba usando la actual v8.1.4 recurrente